# Filtering tf data ZipDataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with images loaded with `image_dataset_from_directory` with 4 classes containing tuples of `(image, label).`
What i did was create a column `'id'` with the same size as the dataset, convert this column to a tf data dataset and concatenate the 2 datasets using :

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, client_id))
```

Resulting to a dataset with signature :

```
<ZipDataset element_spec=((TensorSpec(shape=(128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
```

What i would like to do now is be able to filter this concatenated dataset whenever i want based on the client id value. What i tried is :

```
dataset = dataset.filter( x : x[1]==15)
```

but i get :

```
TypeError: 'ZipDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

However this :

```
for x in dataset.take(1):
  print(x[1])
```

prints the client id correctly :

```
tf.Tensor(15, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[0]` is a tuple and `x[1]` contains the client-ids when iterating over your dataset. Maybe try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)  # ==> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 7)  # ==> [ 4, 5, 6 ]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.zip((a, b)), tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 7)))
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: y==4)
for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=4>) tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Note that `y` refers to the cliend ids in this case.

Comment: This solved it thank you! Is there a way to keep only x in the resulting dataset?

Comment: Sure `dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x)`